# React Native - How to make the others childview not enter a newline?

Tags: css, react-native

[image]

This is my [Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@zhenguet/check)

How can the right view not enter a newline when left view's length stretched to 100%?

My solution is set width with a const. But I want it more optimal by automatic setting, do not use const width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `flexWrap: 'wrap'` from the `check` style (the parent container style) and set `numberOfLines={1}` to achieve the same effect.

This looks as follows.

[image]

The red element will overlap the green elements in this case and it will go off the screen. If this is expected, then we are done.

However, if you want to have the red element fully visible, then you need to add `flex: 1` to the green text element. This looks as follows.

[image]

If you want the ellipsis as an indicator, then you need to remove the `flexWrap: wrap` from the green text element. The result looks as follows.

[image]

Here is [an updated snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/check).

The code for completeness.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.check}>
        <View style={styles.green}>
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.white}>
            Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left
            Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left
            Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left
            Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left
            Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.red}>
          <Text style={styles.white}>Right</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  check: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#ffff',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  green: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    padding: 10,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    // width: '90%'
  },
  red: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 10,
    // width: '10%'
  },
  white: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```